# How can I customize the arrow to select?

Tags: html, css

I have this sample: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/852aseb0/)

```
<div>
    <select>
    <option>Select1</option>
    <option>Select2</option>
    <option>Select35555</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I want to select and customize the arrow in the picture below

[image]

How can I do something? I found some similar posts but I still do not understand how to do... Can you help me please with a simple example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use CSS.

That's an example I found on google for a css template of a select:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/852aseb0/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <select class="select-style">
    <option>Select1</option>
    <option>Select2</option>
    <option>Select35555</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.select-style {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 120px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;

    background: #fff url("http://www.scottgood.com/jsg/blog.nsf/images/arrowdown.gif") no-repeat 90% 50%;
}

.select-style select {
    padding: 5px 8px;
    width: 130%;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
       -moz-appearance: none;
            appearance: none;
}

.select-style select:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

You can modify it and change it like you want it. You can change the size of the arrow too.

Comment: jsfiddle do an update to please?

Comment: @Marius added jsfiddle